# Discord Bot SQL Query Efficiency

Tags: javascript, postgresql, discord.js

Long story short, I have been developing a Discord Bot that requires a query to the database every time a message is sent in a server. It will then perform an action depending on the message etc. The query is asynchronous, therefore it will not block another message from being handled.

However in terms of scalability, I do not believe querying a database every time a message is sent is very speedy and could become a problem. Is there a better solution? I am unaware of a way to store data within a particular discord server, which would likely solve my issue.

My main idea is to have heap storage, where the most recently active servers (ie sent messages recently), their data is queried into the heap, and when they are inactive, it is removed from the heap. Is this a good solution? Or is it better to just keep querying every time?

Comment: Glad I could help :) I'll post this as answer for a better overview. If it works with this or helped you, you can mark it as accepted :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `cache` and every time you `fetch` or `insert` something into your `database` you can write this into the `cache`.

Then, if you need some data you can check if it's in the `cache` and **if not**, get it from the `database` and store it in the `cache` right after.

This prevents unnecessary access to the `database` because the `database` is only accessed if your bot **does not have** the required data stored `locally`.

##### Note:

The `cache` will only be cleared when you **restart the bot**. But of course, you can also clear it after a **certain amount** of **time** or by **other triggers**.

---

If you need an example, you can take a look at my [`guildMemberAdd`](https://github.com/Toasty65/DiscordBot-Jarvis/blob/feature/perServerSettings/events/guild/guildMemberAdd.js) event and the corresponding [`config command`](https://github.com/Toasty65/DiscordBot-Jarvis/blob/feature/perServerSettings/commands/config-commands/setWelcomeMessage.js)